# not being able to load chia through the terminal, how do I fix this?

Tags: command-line

When I go into the terminal and type:

```
cd chia-blockchain-gui
```

I get this message:

```
bash: cd: chia-blockchain-gui: No such file or directory`
```

But when I type:

```
cd chia-blockchain
```

it works perfectly fine. So my next step was to try reinstall the GUI, but when I did that, this happened:

```
jj@shut-up-mike:~$ chmod +x .install-gui.sh
chmod: cannot access '.install-gui.sh': No such file or directory"
```

Here is a link to the GitHub I am using to install this: https://github.com/Chia-Network/chia-blockchain/wiki/INSTALL#ubuntudebian

I must add two really important comments:

1. I have only been using Linux for 3 days.
2. I did have the GUI running fine until I closed the terminal by exiting out of it.

Comment: Note that `.install-gui.sh` is not the same thing as `./install-gui.sh`

Comment: first you try to cd into an app then you cd into a directory in the next step you try to run a command that is not in that directory. Where did you put the stuff you downloaded?

Comment: @David so i am using the mos up to date version and i am not sure where I downloaded it to. how do I find out?

Comment: @steeldriver what is the difference ?

Comment: `.install-gui.sh` refers to a (hidden) file named `.install-gui.sh` whereas `./install-gui.sh` refers to a file named `install-gui.sh` in the current directory, `./`

Comment: Tip: You can use the `ls` command to see what files are in the current directory. Open a terminal and type `ls`. Try out `ls -l` for more detailed information and `ls -a` to show hidden files (`ls -la` also works). Your prompt shows you where you are in the filesystem: the `~` in `user@host:~$` refers to your home directory. You can `cd` ("change directory) into directories (and `cd ..` to come back out - `..` is a reference to the parent of the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cd /home/your_user_name/chia-blockchain && . ./activate && cd chia-blockchain-gui && npm run electron &
```